# swiperjs conditional global styles in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I am using Next.js with SwiperJS where in order for swiper to work I have to import alot of global styles

```
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/effect-fade';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';
import 'swiper/css/autoplay';
import 'swiper/css/zoom';
```

But in order for it to work with next.js it has to be in the _app.tsx file, but that means that nextjs will always load these styles even though SwiperJS is only used in speciall cases. Is it any way to have those styles included conditionally when swiperJS get used? or lazyloaded

I've also tried making a Swiper-component that uses css modules without success.